# Adding C++ headers is breaking Visual studio project compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I've an existing  VS2017 project (Not sure if it's pure C or a C/C++ project) which compiles perfectly fine till i add the below C++ header files.

```
<string>
<vector>
<iostream>
```

The moment i add any of the below C++ header files, it starts throwing the errors as below:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdint(17): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'std'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdint(17): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdint(17): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdint(57): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(19): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(19): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(20): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(22): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(29): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(29): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(30): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cstdlib(32): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(16): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(16): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(17): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(22): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(29): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(30): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(32): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(39): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(40): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(42): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(49): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(49): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(50): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(52): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(59): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(59): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(60): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(62): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(70): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(70): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(71): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(73): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(80): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(80): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(81): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(83): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(90): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(90): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(91): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(93): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(100): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(100): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(101): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(103): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(110): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(110): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(111): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(113): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(120): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(120): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(121): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(123): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(131): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(131): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(132): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(134): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(141): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(141): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(142): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(144): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(151): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(151): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(152): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(154): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(161): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(161): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(162): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(164): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(171): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(171): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(172): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(174): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(181): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(181): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(182): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(184): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(191): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(191): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(192): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(194): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(201): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(201): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(202): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(204): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(211): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(211): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(212): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(214): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(221): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(221): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(222): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(224): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(232): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(232): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(233): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(235): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(243): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\cmath(243): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

> Not sure how do I fix this. How can i make my VS2017 project consume
>   C++ headers also ?

Comment: Needs [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . I suspect that some nasty macro is interfering.

Comment: Do your existing files have ".c" or ".cpp" extension?

Comment: C language doesn't have the above headers. You are probably compiling a C program because your source files end with a _.c_ extension.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this issue fixed by:
Adding the macro _XKEYCHECK_H to preprocessor definition.